# How to prepare school timetable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, timetable

I am new to php and mysql. i am trying to prepare the class timetable in php and mysql like this image.

```
---------------------------------------
Days        9:30AM to 10:15am     10:15 AM to 11:00 AM
---------------------------------------
Monday       Tamil                 English
---------------------------------------
Tuesday      Maths
---------------------------------------
Wednesday
--------------------------------------- and so on
```

this is my database table structure...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mas_batch`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mas_batch` (
  `BatchId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CourseId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BatchName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUserId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MUserId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsActive` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`BatchId`),
  KEY `FK_mas_batch_mas_course` (`CourseId`),
  KEY `FK_mas_batch_mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_mas_batch_mas_course` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseId`) REFERENCES `mas_course` (`CourseId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_mas_batch_mas_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `mas_customer` (`CustomerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `mas_batch`;
INSERT INTO `mas_batch` (`BatchId`, `CustomerId`, `CourseId`, `BatchName`, `CDate`, `CTime`, `CUserId`, `MDate`, `MTime`, `MUserId`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'A', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
    (2, 1, 1, 'B', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
    (3, 1, 2, 'A', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mas_course`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mas_course` (
  `CourseId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CourseName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUserId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MUserId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CourseId`),
  KEY `FK_mas_course_mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_mas_course_mas_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `mas_customer` (`CustomerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `mas_course`;
INSERT INTO `mas_course` (`CourseId`, `CustomerId`, `CourseName`, `CDate`, `CTime`, `CUserId`, `MDate`, `MTime`, `MUserId`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (1, 1, '1st Std', '2014-03-26', NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
    (2, 1, '2nd Std', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
    (3, 1, '4rd Std', NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
    (5, 1, '3rd Std', '2014-04-14', '18:50:02', 1, NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
    (6, 1, '5th Std', '2014-04-14', '18:50:43', 1, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mas_weekdays`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mas_weekdays` (
  `WeekdaysId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Weekdays` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`WeekdaysId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `mas_weekdays`;
INSERT INTO `mas_weekdays` (`WeekdaysId`, `Weekdays`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (1, 'Sunday', 1),
    (2, 'Monday', 1),
    (3, 'Tuesday', 1),
    (4, 'Wednesday', 1),
    (5, 'Thursday', 1),
    (6, 'Friday', 1),
    (7, 'Saturday', 1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mas_weekdays` ENABLE KEYS */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `set_academicyear`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `set_academicyear` (
  `AcademicYearId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AcademicYear` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`AcademicYearId`),
  KEY `FK_set_academicyear_mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_academicyear_mas_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `mas_customer` (`CustomerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `set_academicyear`;
INSERT INTO `set_academicyear` (`AcademicYearId`, `CustomerId`, `AcademicYear`, `SDate`, `EDate`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (1, 1, '2013-2014', '2013-03-01', '2014-03-31', 0),
    (2, 1, '2014-2015', '2014-04-01', '2015-03-31', 1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `set_classtiming`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `set_classtiming` (
  `ClassTimingId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ClassTimingName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `StartTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsBreak` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClassTimingId`),
  KEY `FK_set_classtiming_mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_classtiming_mas_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `mas_customer` (`CustomerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `set_classtiming`;
INSERT INTO `set_classtiming` (`ClassTimingId`, `CustomerId`, `ClassTimingName`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `IsBreak`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (1, 1, '1', '09:30:00', '10:15:00', 0, 1),
    (2, 1, '2', '10:15:00', '11:00:00', 0, 1),
    (3, 1, 'Break', '11:00:00', '11:15:00', 1, 1),
    (4, 1, '3', '11:15:00', '12:00:00', 0, 1),
    (5, 1, '4', '12:00:00', '12:45:00', 0, 1),
    (6, 1, 'LUNCH', '12:45:00', '13:30:00', 1, 1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `set_timetable`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `set_timetable` (
  `TimeTableId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AcademicYearId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CourseId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BatchId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `WeekdaysId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ClassTimingId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SubjectId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`TimeTableId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_mas_course` (`CourseId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_mas_batch` (`BatchId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_set_academicyear` (`AcademicYearId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_set_classtiming` (`ClassTimingId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_mas_subject` (`SubjectId`),
  KEY `FK_set_timetable_set_weekdays` (`WeekdaysId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_mas_batch` FOREIGN KEY (`BatchId`) REFERENCES `mas_batch` (`BatchId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_mas_course` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseId`) REFERENCES `mas_course` (`CourseId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_mas_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_mas_subject` FOREIGN KEY (`SubjectId`) REFERENCES `mas_subject` (`SubjectId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_set_academicyear` FOREIGN KEY (`AcademicYearId`) REFERENCES `set_academicyear` (`AcademicYearId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_set_classtiming` FOREIGN KEY (`ClassTimingId`) REFERENCES `set_classtiming` (`ClassTimingId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_timetable_set_weekdays` FOREIGN KEY (`WeekdaysId`) REFERENCES `set_weekdays` (`WeekdaysId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `set_timetable`;
INSERT INTO `set_timetable` (`TimeTableId`, `CustomerId`, `AcademicYearId`, `CourseId`, `BatchId`, `WeekdaysId`, `ClassTimingId`, `SubjectId`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1),
    (4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 2, 2, 1),
    (5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1),
    (6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1, 2, 1),
    (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1),
    (8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 2, 1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `set_weekdays`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `set_weekdays` (
  `WeekdaysId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Mas_WeekdaysId` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`WeekdaysId`),
  KEY `FK_set_weekdays_mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  KEY `FK_set_weekdays_mas_weekdays` (`Mas_WeekdaysId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_weekdays_mas_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `mas_customer` (`CustomerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_set_weekdays_mas_weekdays` FOREIGN KEY (`Mas_WeekdaysId`) REFERENCES `mas_weekdays` (`WeekdaysId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `set_weekdays`;
INSERT INTO `set_weekdays` (`WeekdaysId`, `CustomerId`, `Mas_WeekdaysId`, `IsActive`) VALUES
    (9, 1, 1, 0),
    (10, 1, 2, 1),
    (11, 1, 3, 1),
    (12, 1, 4, 1),
    (13, 1, 5, 1),
    (14, 1, 6, 1),
    (15, 1, 7, 0);
```

Kindly help to generate timetable for the class...

```
$CustomerId = 1;
$AcademicYearId = 1;
$CourseId = 1;
$BatchId = 1;
$sql_tt = "SELECT * from set_weekdays where IsActive=1";
$res_tt = mysql_query($sql_tt);
if(mysql_num_rows($res_tt))
{
echo '<table id="listing_items" width="auto" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Days</th>';
$sql_classtime = "select * from set_classtiming where IsActive=1";
$res_classtime = mysql_query($sql_classtime);
if(mysql_num_rows($res_classtime)>0)
{
while($row_classtt = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_classtime))
{
if($row_classtt['IsBreak'] == 0)
{
echo '<th>'.time_from_db($row_classtt['StartTime']).'<br />'.time_from_db($row_classtt['EndTime']).'</th>';
}
else
{
echo '<th>'.$row_classtt['ClassTimingName'].'</th>';
}
}
}
echo '</tr>';
while($row_tt = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_tt))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>'.column_name("Weekdays", "mas_weekdays", "WeekdaysId", $row_tt['Mas_WeekdaysId']).'</th>';
$sql_classtime1 = "select * from set_classtiming where IsActive=1 group by ClassTimingId";
$res_classtime1 = mysql_query($sql_classtime1);
if(mysql_num_rows($res_classtime1) > 0)
{
while($row_classtt1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_classtime1))
{
$sql_time = "select * from set_timetable where CustomerId=".$CustomerId." AND AcademicYearId=".$AcademicYearId." AND CourseId=".$CourseId." AND BatchId=".$BatchId;
$res_time = mysql_query($sql_time);
if(mysql_num_rows($res_time) > 0)
{
while($row_time = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_time))
{
if(($row_time['ClassTimingId'] == $row_classtt1['ClassTimingId']))
{
if($row_classtt1['IsBreak'] == 1)
{
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
}
else
{
if(($row_time['WeekdaysId'] == $row_tt['WeekdaysId']))
{
echo '<td>'.column_name("SubjectName", "mas_subject", "SubjectId", $row_time['SubjectId']).'</td>';
}
else
{
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

this is my full coding for generating the time table.... above i pasted my database with datas. Kindly do the needful...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: i want to generate the school timetable. i am unable to show the subject in the concern classtime and weekdays. above given is my database and few coading.

Comment: If anybody having sample school timetable kindly share it to me....

Comment: The problem is nobody is currently understanding you. Which situation are you in? **1** You don't have any table in mysql and cannot print out timetable. **2** You already make a table like in the sample. But you cannot print it out in php as a correct table(nothing comes out or there is errors in php code.). **3.** Some part of the table are missing from the output. Please state whether you are in stage 1,2 or 3. Then most of us will be more undersand about your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am in stage 2. i have already created the database. but unable to create query to get the subject for particular class timing in weekdays. I am unable to share the full database here.

Comment: Anybody please give me solution.

Comment: What do you get from the php code you provide. 1.Nothing 2.Something(please include picture what you get)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While i generate the timetable subjects are not showing in concern cell. it shows in single row. i am unable to share the picture in this site due to less reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Here i shared my coding for your reference. Thanks for your supporting.

```
$CustomerId = 1;
        $AcademicYearId = 1;
        $CourseId = 1;
        $BatchId = 1;

        echo '<table id="listing_items" width="auto" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">';
        $sql_tt = "SELECT * from set_weekdays where IsActive=1";
        $res_tt = mysql_query($sql_tt);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res_tt))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>DAYS</td>';
                $sql_ct = "select * from set_classtiming where IsActive=1";
                $res_ct = mysql_query($sql_ct);
                if(mysql_num_rows($res_ct) > 0)
                {
                    while($row_ct = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_ct))
                    {
                        if($row_ct['IsBreak'] == 0)
                        {
                            echo '<th>'.time_from_db($row_ct['StartTime']).'<br />'.time_from_db($row_ct['EndTime']).'</th>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<th>'.$row_ct['ClassTimingName'].'</th>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            echo '</tr>';
            while($row_tt = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_tt))
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th>'.column_name("Weekdays", "mas_weekdays", "WeekdaysId", $row_tt['Mas_WeekdaysId']).'</th>';
                    $sql_ct = "select * from set_classtiming where IsActive=1";
                    $res_ct = mysql_query($sql_ct);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($res_ct) > 0)
                    {
                        while($row_ct = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_ct))
                        {
                            //echo '<th>'.$row_ct['ClassTimingId'].', '.$row_tt['WeekdaysId'].'</th>';
                            $sql_timetable = "select * from set_timetable where ClassTimingId=".$row_ct['ClassTimingId']." AND WeekdaysId=".$row_tt['WeekdaysId']." AND IsActive=1";
                            $res_timetable = mysql_query($sql_timetable);
                            if(mysql_num_rows($res_timetable) > 0)
                            {
                                while($row_timetable = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_timetable))
                                {
                                    echo '<td>'.column_name("SubjectName", "mas_subject", "SubjectId", $row_timetable['SubjectId']).'</td>';
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I'm sorry , at that time my mom want me to go to bed. lol

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (($row_time['WeekdaysId'] == $row_tt['WeekdaysId'])) {
                echo '<tr><td>' . column_name("SubjectName", "mas_subject", "SubjectId", $row_time['SubjectId']) . '</td></tr>';
```

I added table row tag to your code. Please try if it's working or not. Form what you indicate. You didn't make it into a row

Comment: Above code not working. I had edited my full coding for your reference. it will be useful for fullfill my requiremnts. Kindly help me to generate the time table.

Comment: @user3568389 upload the picture of your current output to a picture host then link me to it. I'm confused by your brackets Xb

Comment: http://yathavtech.info/timetable.png my output from above coading. as per my database data it wrong....

Comment: Anybody please help me complete my request. i already shared my output screen. don't look at my coding. Please share your coding or guide me to complete this task. i am waiting for the reply for more than 8 hours.

Comment: My problem got resolved... kindly mark as solved....